# Chase Rules for Call of Catthulhu [sic]

Tags: chases, call-of-catthulhu

In the simple, and clever, little [Call of Catthulhu RPG](http://www.catthulhu.com/the-game/) the rules are very bare-bones.  Due to this there are some mechanics that seem very important, but do not appear to be detailed.  One of those is chase rules.

Are there set chase rules for Call of Catthulhu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After acquiring a copy of Worlds of Catthulhu and careful review of the two other rule books, I must conclude:

**No**

There are no set rules for chase scenes.